# Cloudbees Jenkins job fails with no console output

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

We are testing out the Cloudbees Jenkins service, but all of our jobs have started to not show any console output. This seems to happen both in jobs that are successful and jobs that fail.

We have created a new job, and cannot see why it is failing since the console output appears empty.

I'm not sure if we have hit some limit in the free version of the service, or if there is some current bug in the service that is preventing the console output from being visible. Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 1):

Restarting your Jenkins should resolve this (this is the 2nd report we've had of this behaviour recently) - please log a support job if that is not the case.

To restart, browse to https://[account].ci.cloudbees.com/restart/

Comment: It looks like another user on your account raised a support ticket about this - we resolved the issue earlier today.

Comment: That said, we are interested in incident reports. If you see this, please let us know so we can look for correlations. In this case, it seems to be due to aborting a job with a grails step.